# POST Guid to WebAPI received as NULL

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am posting an object as JSON to a WebAPI service written in C#. One of the properties is a Guid? (nullable). Even when it's populated however it's being received as a NULL.

To illustrate the issue, I have a C# object.

```
public class TransferObject
{
    public String Name { get; internal set; }

    public Guid? ID { get; internal set; }
}
```

The JSON being sent to the WebService looks like ..

```
{
    "Name":"Robert Smith",
    "ID": "5bcf697c-5db1-4ae8-be28-5f6c4c972fcd"
}
```

And the web service method looks like ...

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponse SaveName([FromBody] TransferObject model)
{
    Guid modelID = model.ID; // returns null
    String name = model.Name // "Robert Smith"
}
```

The Name is being populated correctly. Anyone have any ideas why the Guid is being "nullified" in the **model** argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that String name has value passed in json ? 
I think that public api like yours TransferObject should not have internal properties (and internal setter or getter) if you want to deserialize that with JsonSerializer. JsonSerializer is external .dll and has no access to your setter.

Let's try with public setter.

Comment: Nailed it. If you could post this an answer I will accept it. I don't really want to expose that field for public edit, but this answered the question. Thanks!

Comment: Soo, you can also create a constructor with this parameters, and not expose setters for public. It sounds like an immutable object,

Comment: The object is originally created by a Domain Component with data coming from from the data base and is passed to a web page via a web svc request. A user makes makes modifications to public properties such ad Name (ID is not one of them) via the web form. The form submits the change back to the web service. It's this submit back where it loses the ID. So the OBJECT is not immutable but some properties on it should not be able to be modified.

Comment: Also, the complete object has about 30 properties of which about 5 are internal. I'd rather not pass 20+ properties through a query string nor do I want to, If I don't have to, create a specific data transfer object to pass all that back and forth.